# enable GZIP for response payloads w/ESPv2 on GCP Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-run, envoyproxy, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Did anyone manage to enable GZIP compression for outgoig (aka `downstream`) `application/json`, `text/plain` responses (payloads)?

I traced it down to `[https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/gzip_filter#runtime][1]`, but did not find a way to enable it using ESPv2 docker image…

Update **08/05/2021**:

· Setting `Accept-Encoding: gzip` request header has no effect, returned response is not gzipped.
· And indeed, the new/updated filter is `envoy.filters.http.compressor`

In particular, `https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2/blob/master/src/go/util/marshal.go` does not mention `compressor` (legacy `gzip`) http filter either…

Any ideas?

Comment: I found out that the link you provided is deprecated and there is a new filter/compressor in EnvoyProxy. I also wonder how did you attempt to enable the compression using ESPv2. Knowing that I could try to replicate the issue (if it is still relevant) and provide of a solution.

Comment: @Roger Just double checked, the link is perfectly fine, works and returns 200 Ok.

Comment: @Roger Check `https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2/blob/master/envoy_build_config/extensions_build_config.bzl`

There is no `gzip` nor `compression` filter/extension named `envoy.filters.http.compressor` there…

Comment: From what I can see, the responses have to follow a certain [set of guidelines](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/gzip_filter#:~:text=by%20default%20compression%20will%20be%20skipped%20when%3A) or the compression will be skipped. Make sure you meet all the requirements in your requests and responses to ensure compression is not skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (as of 16th September 2021) gzip compression on ESP v2 is not supported at all, see: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2/issues/607

Comment: Thanks, @dain! This is exactly what I've been trying to explain to `Roger` or whoever they are…