# How to enable text compression when fetching Firestore documents from a Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, brotli

How can I do text compression when retrieving Firestore documents via a Cloud Function?

Let me explain my issue:

I am using a Cloud Function (2nd gen) to return a document from Firestore like so:

```
  try {
    const doc = await db.doc(storyPath).get()
    if (!doc.exists) {
      res.status(404).send('No such document!')
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(doc.data())
    }
  } catch (err) {
    error('Error getting document:', err)
    res.status(500).send('Error getting document')
  }
})
```

However, Google Lighthouse is penalizing me with the following message:

```
Text-based resources should be served with compression (gzip, deflate or brotli) to minimize total network bytes.
URL
Transfer Size
Potential Savings
myapp.web.app 1st Party
384.3 KiB   335.9 KiB
…stories/aidens-first-spell_pdFmlV
384.3 KiB
335.9 KiB
```

I use Firebase Hosting and I see that brotli/gzip is included automatically, but what about cloud functions?

**Do I need to manually include some kind of text compression ?**

For additional context, here is the request/response headers for this fetched document:

`Response`:

```
Accept-Ranges:
bytes
Alt-Svc:
h3=":443";ma=86400,h3-29=":443";ma=86400,h3-27=":443";ma=86400
Cache-Control:
private
Content-Length:
393495

Content-Type:
text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:
Tue, 19 Dec 2023 14:35:29 GMT
Server:
Google Frontend
Strict-Transport-Security:
max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
Vary:
cookie,need-authorization, x-fh-requested-host, accept-encoding
X-Cache:
MISS
X-Cache-Hits:
0
X-Cloud-Trace-Context:
fd52c17b88def1d5c73787f6a8a7973c;o=1
X-Country-Code:
US
X-Orig-Accept-Language:
en-US,en;q=0.9
X-Powered-By:
Nuxt
X-Served-By:
cache-stl760066-STL
X-Timer:
S1702996529.754829,VS0,VE360
```

`Request`:

```
:authority:
bmyapp.web.app
:method:
GET
:path:
/users/kRUx8ZxLoUd0y7kTcxgPfwTiGu13/stories/aidens-first-spell_pdFmlV
:scheme:
https
Accept:
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control:
no-cache
Dnt:
1
Pragma:
no-cache
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
document
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site:
same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User:
?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:
1
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/121.0.0.0
```

Comment: "*Do I need to manually include some kind of text compression?*" - maybe give it a try and see what happens? Or are you asking someone to do this for you?

Comment: Cloud Run (which services Cloud Functions v2 behind the scenes) doesn't compress responses by default.  Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76205422/how-to-compress-automatically-cloud-run-responses), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093990/enable-gzip-for-response-payloads-w-espv2-on-gcp-cloud-run), [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147185337#comment21). If you use Cloud Run directly, maybe you can pass a special flag as explained [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2/issues/607#issuecomment-1113530544), which is fairly new.

Comment: If you want the Firebase wrappers to give you the option to compress responses in Cloud Run natively, file a feature request on [firebase-tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) and/or [firebase-functions](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions).

Comment: I don't get how Lighthouse (runs in the browser, right?) is warning you about communication between a Cloud Function and Firestore ?  Is your browser invoking the Cloud Function, and if so how?  Is Lighthouse complaining about Firestore, or just the communication between the browser and the Cloud Function?